# I need SSO and Maven to work together in a Tomcat 9 Eclipse project, I have check the usual suspects but I think I missed something

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, single-sign-on, http-status-code-404

Tomcat 9.0.87
msal-b2c-web-sample

My server and maven looked to be built correctly, but I get that 404 error. it does not make sense to me why to projects that are built correctly cant mix, am I not installing my MVN right in my tomcat project with Eclipse?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmzHY.png)

Here is my pom if it helps, but I am more green on this, I built the server and project directly with Eclipse, so I dont know why it does not work, when I have used tomcat in the past all my html and jsp do work, and are found, and when I say Run As and select Run on Server I tell it to use my tomcat 9 server

So I expect that its suppose to run it in there, do I need to load it in webapps\ROOT, I thought that eclipse took care of that

Other thing I need help with is that the index, auth-page and error-page have the tags for my SSO and I have my application settings, but with this I dont know if there is a second issue to my page, so if you have any questions on that or suggestion to watch for in my SSO code from msal B2C from microsoft.

First time going into SSO, any help is golden, Thanks

```
*`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>msal-b2c-web-sample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <name>msal-b2c-web-sample</name>
    <description>B2C Web sample for Microsoft Authentication Library for Java</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1</version>
                      
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                          
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                          
                   
                         
                         
                    
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
                                 
    </build>
</project>`*
```